# Change Spring config connection in runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I need to change my connection with the Database in runtime. For Example, if parameter requested is BD1, connect on database 1, if BD2, connect in database 2, etc.

I am using spring boot. What is the best way for this.

I have this `@Configuration`, but not know to say my repository how to use.

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "ccteste")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.ciclocairu.teste.datasource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource ciclocairuTeste() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ccprod")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.ciclocairu.prod.datasource")
    public DataSource ciclocairuProd() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "tmccteste")
    @Autowired
    @Primary
    DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManagerCicloCairuTeste(@Qualifier("ccteste") DataSource datasource) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager txm = new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
        return txm;
    }

    @Bean(name = "tmccprod")
    @Autowired
    @Primary
    DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManagerCicloCairuProd(@Qualifier("ccprod") DataSource datasource) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager txm = new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
        return txm;

    }
}
```

Comment: Search on multi tenant if this is _really_ needed.  However, creating beans based on the environment (test vs prod) seems inappropriate.  There should be one DataSource bean, where the bean is configured from one property file.  The values in the property file are based on the environment.

Comment: thanks, i understood, but, this not only prod vs test, the idea is my system can connect in others subsidiaries the my company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for some data source routing. Spring has [AbstractRoutingDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) for run-time detection what data source should be used.

> Abstract DataSource implementation that routes getConnection() calls
>   to one of various target DataSources based on a lookup key.

Also you can set default datasource by `setDefaultTargetDataSource` method.

It works in such way: you put data sources that you need in a map in AbstractRoutingDataSource at the bean configuration stage, and when you need to use a specific data source you put the key for this source into the context that linked to the router. This ds-key is linked to the current thread.

Here are examples : [Dynamic DataSource Routing with Spring](http://fedulov.website/2015/10/14/dynamic-datasource-routing-with-spring/)  and [Spring DataSource Routing](http://kimrudolph.de/blog/spring-datasource-routing)

Comment: thanks, i got it. but i have a doubt. if, for example, two requests are made with different databases in short interval time. The spring can manage this ?

Comment: spring router works by threadLocal class. for the different request, you use different instance of the local variable. so from this case, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Might take a look at my answer at [Manage transactions with multiple datasource, entity managers for same application code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562425/manage-transactions-with-multiple-datasource-entity-managers-for-same-applicati/48567242#48567242)

or my blog post: [Multi-tenant applications using Spring Boot, JPA, Hibernate and Postgres](http://tech.asimio.net/2017/01/17/Multitenant-applications-using-Spring-Boot-JPA-Hibernate-and-Postgres.html)