# Create spring datasource at runtime

Tags: spring, jdbc

Is there any possible solution to dynamically create a datasource at runtime? I have come across `AbstractRoutingDataSource` e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648842/change-spring-config-connection-in-runtime) a few times however in my case I would not know the database name at the time of config beans starting up as we will be creating databases during client on-boarding and would prefer not to have to bounce the app, so I would want to select the correct datasource based on some client id in the request header, and add the new datasource to the spring context on the first request for this client.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like any other bean you can add DataSource bean in runtime.
There are several ways to do this: https://medium.com/@venkivenki4b6/spring-dynamically-register-beans-in-4-ways-at-run-time-c1dc45dcbeb9